# show locations from database on map within a radius of another location

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, maps

I want to select an address from a drop down list and find the addresses from a different table with a 5 mile radius and show the addresses on a map. I am using SQL server database and vb.net. This is for a web app.

I have searched this forum and Google and I am unable to find anything that shows how to do this with a one to many relationship.

Comment: What exactly do you need help with?

Comment: I don't know how to implement it. I assume that JavaScript would be used. I don't know how to write the JavaScript.

Comment: If the "different table" has spatial fields (lat/long points) you have a pretty good shot at a solution. If the "different table" is just text addresses a simple solution is unlikely. Search for the topic `geocoding`

Comment: My tables have the spatial fields and geocordinate.